# Will spark keep not needed data in the unbounded table?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I think I understand the concepts but still something is unclear for me:

Lets says we have structured streaming reading the following data from some source:

```
id,name,age
1, Joe, 34
2, Frank,69
3,Eva,62
..etc
```

As far I understand Spark reads it from the source , put it in the unbounded table, run some logic on it and write to the result table.

My questions is that if I have a logic something like getting only the name column :

```
df.select("name")
```

Will the Spark read all columns from the input table then make the selection or drop all the non-name columns from the input table then read everything(which is only the name at this point) from the table?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the word "some" in your phrase "data from some source".

If it's some column base storage, like Parquet, it should read only the needed columns.

If it's raw files/records at HDFS/S3/Kafka/etc, Spark has to read a whole record, do split it by column, and drop non-necessary columns after that.

Comment: "Raw Parquet" can be stored in S3/HDFS, so are you contradicting the second and third statements?